# How to update x-data component in a js function

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

**Q1:**

I am trying to create a form which is populated with initial values fetched from an API. Everytime the user edits any of the fields in the form, a POST request should be sent to the API and the initial values should be then updated. My current solution works, but as I'm using it in a for-loop in a django template, the readability of the resulting html file is suboptimal as the script is repeated very many times. I think extracting the fetch script to a function would make the template much more readable, but I don't know how to update the contents of the x-data component containing all the values user has given in the form in a function.

Current solution looks like this (styles etc unnecessary cleaned):

```
    <form action="/submitcars" method="POST" 
        x-data="{ dynamic_cars: [] }"
        x-init="dynamic_cars = await (await fetch('/dynamic_cars')).json()">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row-container">
            {% for row in rows %}
                {% for i in 0|range:3 %}
                  <div class="input_container car-{{i}}" x-show="open">
                    <div class="edited_icon" x-show="dynamic_cars.cars[{{i}}].{{row.row_id}}.user_edited === 'true'">
                      <i class="material-icons refresh" @click="dynamic_cars.cars[{{i}}].{{row.row_id}}.user_edited = 'false'">refresh</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="edited_icon" x-show="dynamic_cars.cars[{{i}}].{{row.row_id}}.user_edited === 'false'"></div>
                    <input required
                    step="any"
                    id=id_form_car_{{i}}-{{row.row_id}}
                    name=form_car_{{i}}-{{row.row_id}}
                    type="{{row.html_type}}"
                    tabindex="{{i}}" 
                    x-model.lazy="dynamic_cars.cars[{{i}}].{{row.row_id}}.value"
                    @change= "dynamic_cars.cars[{{i}}].{{row.row_id}}.user_edited = 'true',
                    dynamic_cars = await (
                    await fetch('/dynamic_cars', {
                      method: 'POST', 
                      headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'X-CSRFToken': document.head.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').content  
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(dynamic_cars)
                    })).json()"></input>
                    <div class="unit" x-text="dynamic_cars.cars[{{i}}].{{row.row_id}}.unit"></div>
                  </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="submit-button">
          <button type="submit" value="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
        ...
```

EDIT: Added the django loops and variables to question. row.row_id has the property name which tells the information (make, model etc) I am showing on each row in a CSS grid. So all three cars have these properties. row.row_id's match the property names in dynamic_cars API response:

```
cars: [
        {
          {make: {value: "Toyota", unit: "", user_edited: "false"},
          {model: {value: "Camry", unit: "", user_edited: "false"},
          ...
          70+ more properties for each car
          ...
        },
        {...},
        {...}
      ]
```

Instead of having the whole POST-fetch after the x-on:change, I would like to have something like:

```
x-on:change="postCars(dynamic_cars)"

<script>
    async function postCars(dynamic_cars) {
      response = await fetch('/dynamic_cars', {
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-CSRFToken': document.head.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').content  
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(dynamic_cars)
      })
      .then(response => {
          if(response.ok) return response.json();
             })
    }
</script>
```

By doing this, I can see that the POST request in the script has the data in dynamic_cars in its payload, and the response is correct, but the dynamic_cars object is set empty and the initial values in the form disappear if the input is edited. How should this be done correctly?

**Q2:**

Another question I have which is a little off-topic, but which probably is related to very basics of javascript is that the console in browser dev-tools shows error messages:

```
Alpine Expression Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Expression: "dynamic_cars.cars[1].make.value"

AND

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')
```

Does this mean I have to define/initialize dynamic_cars in x-data exactly as the API returns? What if the API response is very complex and has lots of data or is even unknown? Writing the x-data="{}" open would mean hundreds of rows of javascript, which I wouldn't bother to write and maintain as the current solution works otherwise as intended, except for the console errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see those error messages in the console is that you try to bind form fields to non-existing objects. In the Alpine.js environment you only have an empty list: `x-data="{ dynamic_cars: [] }"`. When Alpine.js initially try to bind input field to the respective variable, e.g. `dynamic_cars.cars[1].make.value`, the `dynamic_cars` does not even have a `cars` attribute, in fact, it is not even an object, but a list, so there's a type error as well.

After the faulty data-binding cycle, Alpine.js executes the code you provided in `x-init` that fetches the backend and finally updates the `dynamic_cars` variable, so now it has those attributes/fields you try to bind form fields previously. Surprisingly it's still working somehow, but IMHO it's rather undefined behavior and should be avoided.

But since you know the number of items/attributes in your form, it is trivial to create the correct JS data structure for them, so Alpine.js can bind them to the respective form fields. And after we fetch the backend we just have to update this object with the fetched data and Alpine.js updates the DOM automatically.

```
<form action="/submitcars" method="POST" x-data="carsForm" @change="postCars">
  <div>
  {% for row in rows %}
      {% for i in 0|range:3 %}
        <div class="input_container car-{{i}}" x-show="open">
          <div class="edited_icon" x-show="dynamic_cars.cars[{{i}}].{{row.row_id}}.user_edited">
            <i class="material-icons refresh" @click="dynamic_cars.cars[{{i}}].{{row.row_id}}.user_edited = false">refresh</i>
          </div>
          <div class="edited_icon" x-show="dynamic_cars.cars[{{i}}].{{row.row_id}}.user_edited"></div>
          <input required
                step="any"
                id=id_form_car_{{i}}-{{row.row_id}}
                name=form_car_{{i}}-{{row.row_id}}
                type="{{row.html_type}}"
                tabindex="{{i}}"
                x-model.lazy="dynamic_cars.cars[{{i}}].{{row.row_id}}.value" />
          <div class="unit" x-text="dynamic_cars.cars[{{i}}].{{row.row_id}}.unit"></div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <div class="submit-button">
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Tallenna</button>
  </div>
</form>


<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('carsForm', () => ({
    dynamic_cars: {cars: {
    {% for i in 0|range:3 %}
    {{ i }}: {
      {% for row in rows %}
      {{ row.row_id }}: {value: '', user_edited: true, unit: ''},
      {% endfor %}
    },
    {% endfor %}
    }},

    init() {
      this.getCars()
    },

    getCars() {
      // ... fetch backend as usual

      // Sync new data with local this.dynamic_cars
      this.syncData(response.json())
    },

    syncData(new_data) {
      for (let i in new_data.cars) {
        let car = new_data.cars[i]
        for (let property_name in car) {
          for (let prop_attr of ['value', 'unit', 'user_edited']) {
            this.dynamic_cars.cars[i][property_name][prop_attr] = car[property_name][prop_attr]
          }
        }
      }
    },

    postCars() {
      // Post to the backend with payload: JSON.stringify(this.dynamic_cars)

      // Sync response data with local this.dynamic_cars
      this.syncData(response.json())
    }
  }))
})
</script>
```

Our Alpine.js component is called `carsForm` and we used the [Alpine.data()](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data) in the `alpine:init` event that ensures Alpine.js is ready in our environment. You see that the HTML template contains only minimal Alpine.js-related attributes: an `x-data` and `@change` and the data-binding ones.

First, we create the empty `dynamic_cars` Alpine.js variable, that has as many rows/items/attributes/etc as needed, so Alpine.js can bind each of them to the respective form fields.

In the `getCars()` method executed from `init()`, we fetch the backend and call `syncData()` function with the response data as an argument. This function iterates over the deeply nested data structure and updates the corresponding  value in our local `dynamic_cars` variable. After that Alpine.js updates the DOM.

After the user updates a form field the `@change` directive calls our `postCars()` method that post to the backend with payload `dynamic_cars`. When the backend responds, we call `syncData()` again to update the local `dynamic_cars` variable with the latest version of the data from the backend.

Note: the `user_edited` will be parsed, so you don't have to make string comparison, just use as a boolean variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative answer. First of all I learned a lot and try this asap. I had a clue I should use alpine.data() but did not know how. 

I'm updating the dynamic_cars right after posting to the backend, because other input fields in the form are "smart" meaning that their initial values are dependent on values in other input fields. It is not shown here, but I'm also sending information if the input is user-edited or not, and if the input is user-edited, then the response is the same. Otherwise initial value in the input field is changed in the response.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I've refactored the sync part of the code into a separate `syncData()` method that we can call in both `getCars()` and `postCars()` functions. So when the backend updates some fields based on the user input data, we sync these dependent fields with the reactive Alpine.js variables. See my updated answer.

Comment: I tried this and managed to get the proposed solution work as intended. However, in this page I need to show only 3 cars at a time and each of them includes 70+ objects(make, model, price etc) and then they have three objects (value, unit, user_edited). This means it requires 210+ lines of code both in the syncData and postCars to be maintained. This would still be fine, but the biggest issue considering my use and skills is that in this solution I am forced to find for example cars[1].consumption.value using number (position in the arrays) instead of just using the property name.

Comment: Well, I did not know these details. 70+ objects is a lot, I do not recommend to maintain them by hand. You mean '1' in `cars[1]` is a unique value, e.g. a primary key? Could you share the relevant Django models? Of course not the whole 70+ fields, but a few relevant ones, because now we need some kind of model field serializer that produces a JS data structure for the Alpine.js component. I need to make sure I understand your data models on the backend correctly, since half of the problem is Django-related.

Comment: Yes that's definitely very understandable, should probably have included everything right away. Now the Django stuff and brief specification of the data model / API are added in the original question.

Comment: Thanks! Now I think I understand the data structure, I edited my answer with a new method. We construct the correct `dynamic_cars` Alpine.js variable with Django in the `carsForm` component. After posting, we call the `syncData()` method with the new data from the backend, that updates the local `dynamic_cars` then Alpine.js updates the DOM. (You cannot directly replace `dynamic_cars` with the new object from the data because it will loose reactivity.)

Comment: Thousand thanks, works like a charm now! I had to make some minor edits mostly to the Django loops so that they do not produce unwanted commas or braces after last round of looping but other than that this was a clear solution as it is. Never thought on using django variables in scripts but it was brilliant.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it finally worked. Yes, a little bit unusual to use Django templates like a macro system to generate JS source code, but it gets the job done. I've also used Jinja2 (similar to Django templates) to generate C++ source code based on the input parameters. It was much friendlier than C macros.